# C# for loop to display all records

Tags: c#, wpf, for-loop

I am doing this in wpf c# , I am trying to populate some records from a database.  There are 21 records.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
private void PopulateQuestion(int activityID, int taskID)
{
    IList<ModelSQL.question> lstQuestion = qn.GetRecords(taskID, activityID);

    for( int i= 0 ; i<=lstQuestion.Count()-1; i++)
    {
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.FontSize = 19;
        tb.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        tb.Text = lstQuestion[i].QuestionContent;
        tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow;
        wrapPanel1.Children.Add(tb);

        TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
        if (lstQuestion[i].Answer.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            tbox.FontSize = 19;
            tbox.Width = 100;
            tbox.Height = 40;
            tbox.PreviewDrop += new DragEventHandler(tbox_PreviewDrop);
            tbox.Focusable = false; // Disallow user to input anything into it.
            wrapPanel1.Children.Add(tbox);
        }
        answers.Add(lstQuestion[i].Answer);

        if (lstQuestion[i].QuestionNo != lstQuestion[i + 1].QuestionNo)
        {
            StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
            sp.Width = 1010;
          //  wrapPanel1.Children.Add(sp);
            Label spacing = new Label();
            spacing.Width = 1038;
            spacing.Content = "";
            wrapPanel1.Children.Add(spacing);
        }

    } // end of for each loop.
}
```

I don't know what is related and what is not, so I just post the part where the for loop lies . the `lstQuestion.Count()` has 21 counts which is 21 records from database, however I got this error:

> {"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size
>   of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"}

So, I suppose something got to do with the for loop where **i <=lstQuestion.Count()** .

I tried to put **i<=lstQuestion.Count()-2** ,

it works but it doesn't display the last 2 records, it displays 19 records instead of 21.

How do I change the for loop such that it displays all 21 records?

I can't use foreach loop because I need to find the next loop value when I am in my current loop.

Comment: check this line. 
`if (lstQuestion[i].QuestionNo != lstQuestion[i + 1].QuestionNo)`
What happens when I reaches 20? and you try to compare it with the 21st record!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's throwing the exception on:

```
if (lstQuestion[i].QuestionNo != lstQuestion[i + 1].QuestionNo)
```

When you get to your last (21st) record, it's trying to compare to the 22nd, which doesn't exist.

You need to decide what should happen in the last iteration of your loop. At the very least, something like:

```
if (i + 1 < lstQuestion.Count())
{
    if (lstQuestion[i].QuestionNo != lstQuestion[i + 1].QuestionNo)
    ...
```